# Problems with Safecracker updating Status after upgrade to EE2.6.1

Tags: safecracker, ee2-upgrades, status

I have a simple safecracker form to allow a member group change the status of an entry

```
{exp:safecracker 
channel="{channel_name}" 
return="/template/" 
author_only="no" 
include_jquery="no" 
safecracker_head="no" 
datepicker="no"
use_live_url="no"
entry_id="{segment_3}"
id="apply_status"}
     {status_menu}
    <select name="status" tabindex="1">
        {select_options}
    </select>
{/status_menu}  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="2" id="apply_status">
{/exp:safecracker}
```

This was working fine until I upgraded to ee2.6.1. The issue is if the Entry author is in a different member_group than the editor member_group I am given the "you are not authorised to perform this action" error.

The editor member_group has permission to:
Post and edit entries in the channel
Can edit entries authored by others

I thought the problem might be related to this bug in2.6
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19335
But that seems to be corrected in 2.6.1

Super-Admins do not get this error.

Can anyone replicated this error or is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Are you using a custom statuses, and if so, has the member group in question been granted access to those statuses?

Comment: Yes I am using Custom Statuses and the member group has been granted access to them through Admin > Channel Admin > Statuses > Custom Group Name > Custom Status Name

Comment: Did you have any luck with this, i have a feeling we are getting the same problem...

Comment: No I'm afraid not. I'll have to send a bug report. Been dragged away on another job for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug fix mentioned here

http://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20084

> Please make sure these seemingly unrelated settings are set:
>
> The original author’s group has to have “Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?” set to “Yes”
>
> The person attempting to make the edit must have “Can change the author name when > posting channel entries” set to “Yes”